# Portable virtualized linux on usb with persistence lauched from any windows PC without administrator right

Tags: linux, usb, admin, virtualbox, portable-applications

Hello Stackoverflow community,

I don't know if it's possible but I would like to have a portable linux Ubuntu OS on my USB stick:

1. wich I can **lauch** from **any windows PC** where I **don't** have **administrator right**
2. without having to "boot on it" but with **launching it as an "application"** in the windows OS (as MS excel for example and probably with virtualbox, vmware, or others)
3. without **installing anything** on the windows host PC
4. which **keep the persistence** (I want to work on this portable OS, install things, and find them again at the next start.)

Is that possible?

I'v found many things on the net but each time and for what I understood:

- either you need the admistrator right (portable virtualbox)
- or it cannot keep the persistence (live linux) so I have no choice to boot on the portable linux OS (wich I don't want)
- or it's not portable so I have to install things on the PC I'm trying to work on

Any suggestion, idea, workaround would be strongly appreciated.

Thanks in advance,

Mat

Comment: I think this is a better question for the ask Ubuntu forum.

Comment: Yes, you're right and it's done. Here's the [thread](https://forum.ubuntu-fr.org/viewtopic.php?id=1881541) for those who are interested by the topic (in french).

Answer (score 0):

I am aware that qemu does not require administrator rights.  The problem is all virtualisation solutions require administrator rights either at installation time or in the case of portability beginning of runtime.

[Qemu](http://qemu.weilnetz.de/) is not virtualisation, it is emulation so would be slower than virtualisation.  It does run Linux, have persistance and is portable.

On the plus side, you can run amd64 on 32 bit machines (even slower), mips, arm and other architectures also.